# Mass Spec - What could a loss of 28amu as the first fragmentation be?

Tags: spectroscopy, mass-spectrometry

I guess 28 could be CO, C2H4 or N2. However I can't work out a mechanism by which CO could be the first fragmentation of any common organic compound. It seems like a diazonium salt could lose N2 as the first fragmentation but I've reason to believe this is not the unknown compound I'm trying to work out.

Comment: You should remember that the species that undergo fragmentation aren't common compounds but excited radical cations.

Comment: Hi Mithoron thanks for your reply. I understand that the molecular ion is a radical cation, but I don't understand how the molecular ion could lose just CO. COH I understand but not just CO.

Comment: If you had an aldehyde which formed a radical cation and had loss of a hydrogen radical, a subsequent fragmentation could easily be loss of CO.  You to need to look at homolytically splitting your bonds. The other option is a Mclafferty rearrangement for loss of ethene

Comment: Hmm, it's possible IMO for some of cyclic ketons to lose CO as first, with contraction of ring.